# cURL not working (send/receive), php5-fpm and nginx

Tags: php, curl, nginx, mysqli

I was recently tasked with creating a script that would accomplish several things:
- Parse data from $_POST
- Insert that data into a local database
- Send that data as POST to a third party

The first two goals are simple. Get the data, sanitize and validate it, insert it into my database. Done, done, and done.

I'm running into an issue with the third goal. Upon reviewing my options I determined that cURL would fit the bill, but unfortunately, I'm not able to get it to work. I've tried searching around SO and Google, but my search results haven't turned up anything useful.

**Here's my "insert_data.php" file**. There are no errors, no failures, nothing. It works like a charm if I manually define an array for `$data`.

```
<?php
$data = $_POST;

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database_name');

$key_list = implode(',', array_keys($data));
$val_list = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($data), '?'));
$types    = str_repeat('s', count($data));
$query    = "INSERT INTO leads ($key_list) VALUES ($val_list)";

if ( !$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query) ) 
{
  die('connection error');
} else
{
  $stmt->bind_param($types, $data['first_name'], $data['last_name'], $data['email'])

  if ( !$stmt->execute() )
  {
    die('execution error');
  }
  else
  {
    die('success');
  }
}
?>
```

**Here's my "send_curl.php" file**. I think there's something wrong with my cURL usage, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

```
<?php
$data = array(
  'first_name' => 'John',
  'last_name'  => 'Doe',
  'email'      => 'user@domain.com',
);

$url = 'insert_data.php';

$fields = '';
foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
  $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
}
rtrim($fields, '&');

$post = curl_init();
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($post);
curl_close($post);

if (isset($result))
{
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($result);
  echo "</pre>";
}
else
{
  die('$result not set');
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Your help is **much** appreciated.

Comment: try: `$url = 'http://yoursite.com/insert_data.php';` - With absolute URLs

Comment: JakeGould replied with the same thing; I upvoted your comment and accepted his post as the answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in your code & is not a URL:

```
$url = 'insert_data.php';
```

The URL should be a full URL like this:

```
$url = 'http://my.great.site.here/insert_data.php';
```

More details on how the [`curl_init`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) URL is handled can be found on [the official PHP manual entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php).

Comment: You and @aldanux are lifesavers, I've been going insane. I figured this simple api was something I didn't need to set up a server block and host cover for to do local testing... big sigh of relief knowing that was the only issue. Accepted as the answer. Thanks again!